# Ir mostrando los resultados de una petición ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Buen día,

estoy haciendo una petición ajax(jquery) en obtengo un resultado, el cual es el siguiente:

```
  Informacion enviada a diego
  Informacion enviada a carlos
  Informacion enviada a andres
  Informacion enviada a sergio
  Informacion enviada a camilo
  Información enviada a miguel
```

este es el script

```
  $.ajax({   
    url  : '/recursos/verDestinatarios.php',
    data : { opcion : $opcion },
    type : 'POST',
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $cargar.html("<img src='/imagenes/ajax-loader.gif' />");
    },
    success : function(data) {
        $cargar.empty();
        $cargar.css('display','block');
        $cargar.html(data); 
    }
});
```

y verDestinatarios.php es un simple for

```
 foreach($opcion as value){
    echo "Informacion enviada a ".$value;
 }
```

el asunto no esta en el resultado, sino en el como mostrar el resultado, pues el resultado se muestra en bloque, pero quisiera que se mostrar uno a uno, gracias por su atención.

Comment: Si nos muestras el código te podríamos ayudar.

Comment: Quieres que en una sola línea se muestre si se ha enviado información a diego, carlos, andres, etc?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo, hola roberto, no no en una sola linea, mas o menos es: la peticion ajax envió a diego se muestre en ese instante, se envió a carlos se muestre en ese instante, tal y como lo tengo me imprime todo en bloque, y lo necesito es que se vaya mostrado uno a uno los resultados.

Comment: ahí puse el codigo @Jemonge ;)

Comment: entonces todo depende de los valores que tengas en tu variable "opcion", procura que esa variable tome un solo nombre a la vez, si envías todos los nombres a la vez, el foreach del php te los mostrará todos.

Comment: Lo que yo te recomendaría es retornar la información como objeto o array JSON desde el script. Luego iteras sobre ``data`` en la llamada AJAX, y utilizando ``setTimeout``, colocas un delay por cada interación para que tus resultados se muestren uno por uno como deseas.

Comment: Solo como curiosidad, ¿Por qué usar específicamente PHP para esto? Así como requieres se muestra tu información, se puede hacer con solo JavaScript `setTimeout` y un arreglo de mensajes que se vayan mostrando dentro del timeout, ahora solo resta suponer que más adelante usarás esta funcionalidad para algo ya más grande.

Comment: Ummm, el archivo `verDestinatarios.php` siempre te mostrará los datos como un bloque, `PHP` se ejecuta y crea el html para luego mostrarlo todo a la vez. Por otro lado podrías hacerlo como comenta @ÁngelCamiloChávez, desde la llamada ajax envías los datos uno a uno, no todos a la vez.

Comment: @Lixus lo que pasa es que estoy reumiendo lo del php, porque es un script largo que procesa unos datos, resumiento todo esos datos en un array y con el foreach voy devolviendo los resultados, no es tan simple como se en cuanto al script php, por eso digo que lo que me importa es como se muestran los resultados generados por el php.

Comment: @ÁngelCamiloChávez podrías darme una pequeña orientación en código, con lo que esta ahí, gracias

Answer (score 2):

En php puedes guardar tus resultados en un archivo temporal, codificados en JSON

```
 $a=array();
 foreach($opcion as $value){
    array_push($a, $value);
    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($a));
    fclose($fp);
 }
```

ejecutamos el primer AJAX, en el success marcamos el clear interval que crearemos para el segundo AJAX:

```
$.ajax({   
    url  : '/recursos/verDestinatarios.php',
    data : { opcion : $opcion },
    type : 'POST',
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $cargar.html("<img src='/imagenes/ajax-loader.gif' />");            
    },
    success : function(data) {
        clearInterval(tictac);
    }
});
```

creamos un interval para verificar el progreso cada medio segundo:

```
var tictac = setInterval(getprogress(), 500);
```

nuestro segundo segundo AJAX se hará sobre el archivo JSON, el cual llamamos desde el interval para que vuelva a realizarse hasta que el primer AJAX nos diga que ha terminado

```
function getprogress(){

        $.getJSON( "/recursos/results.json", function() {
          console.log( "leyendo" );
          })
          .done(function(data) {
            console.log( "leido" );
            $cargar.html('');
            for (i in data){ 
              $cargar.append('<p>Información enviada a '+data[i]+'</p>'); 
            }                 
          });
 }
```

como las llamadas AJAX son asíncronas ambas seguirán corriendo al mismo tiempo y cuando termine la primera hará terminar la segunda.

Comment: muchas gracias estoy intentando hacerlo a la manera que lo dices y me parece bien solo que al momento de crear el archivo json, ide me marca error en ese archivo json, el formato que se crea queda asi:

["diego"]["carlos"]["jaime"]["jesus"]

Comment: si inicializas `$a=array();` afuera de tu `for`

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien, deseas hacer una descarga progresiva (recibir trozos de tu descarga mientras van llegando). Hasta donde sé, utilizando el API ajax de JQuery no hay forma de hacer lo que quieres. La solucion más simple es modificar tu código PHP para que te envíe los datos de uno a uno, o de 5 en 5, o de 10 en 10 (estilo páginación).

Si eso no es una opción, hay trucos para hacer lo que quieres (busca por `overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');` ),  pero no son fáciles de implementar y son propensos a errores (los he tenido que usar para hacer data-streaming así que tengo conocimiento de causa).

Para implementar la paginacion en PHP, podrías enviar un parámetro "página" desde jquery en el URL, llamémosle p. Suponiendo que van de 10 en 10, recibes a p en PHP y envias solamente los elementos p*10, p*10+1 hasta p*10+9 de tu arreglo/base de datos/fichero o lo que sea que estas usando como origen de datos.

Comment: si es algo así como tu lo describes, osea lo que se va ejecutando que se vaya mostrando, lo que pasa es que con click en un botón se debe ejecutar esa tarea y en esa misma ejecución quiero conseguir ese resultado, como seria una modificación al php?

Comment: Pudiera utilizar websockets, el servidor notificaría por cada registro la operación terminada y se le acumularían al cliente las respuestas. Te debo el código ahora es que estoy leyendo acerca de ws, aunque como lo veo, lleva algo de implementación en php. Hasta yo pronto estaré preguntando por acá sobre WS.

Comment: @Francisco si, muy cierto que con websockets tambien se puede, y es de hecho la solucion "moderna" al problema en general, pero para esta caso en particular, un paginado normalito me parece mas apropiado y mas simple de implementar (me disculpan la falta de acentos)

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacer un `.split("\r")` para dividir cada linea y agregarla a un `array`.

luego cargar cada uno con un `for` y con un `delay` hacer una pausa entre cada uno

```js
 function cargar(){
 
  var data="Informacion enviada a diego\rInformacion enviada a carlos\r Informacion enviada a andres\rInformacion enviada a sergio\rInformacion enviada a camilo\rInformación enviada a miguel"

  var res = data.split("\r");
  for (p in res){
    var item = $('<p  class="test">'+res[p]+'</p>').hide().delay(500*p).slideDown( "fast" );
    $('#result').append(item);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
<button onclick='cargar()'>cargar</button>
```

Comment: si es así exactamente como quiero que se vaya mostrando, pero entonces tendría que esperar a que el servidor termine de hacer todo el trabajo, guardar todas las respuestas en un array y luego hacer le proceso que tu mencionas, pensé que se podía hacer así en tiempo real por decirlo de alguna manera.

Comment: ok, esto es lo que había entendido de tu pregunta. viéndolo de esa manera es mas complicado, necesitarías hacer correr tu primer php el cual guardaría los resultados en otro lado (una bd, un archivo temporal), luego llamar un segundo php que lea los resultados, cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: me suena mucho lo del archivo lo voy a intentar por ese lado =D cualquier ayuda extra te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1):

Hola una forma sencilla de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

1- Modificar el PHP: Agrego el caracter "|". Para dividir la respuesta con el split en javascript

```
$string = null;
foreach($opcion as value){
     $string .= "Informacion enviada a ".$value . "|";
}

echo $string
```

2- Agregar este script - Es una funcion que recibe el string con el caracter "|". Lo convierte a un array con el .split. Y luego recorre el array con un For. Sin embargo, se agrega un delay de 0,5 segundos para mostrar las distintas respuestas.

```
function mostrarDatos()
{
 $("#cargar").html("<img src='/imagenes/ajax-loader.gif' />");
 $.post('/recursos/verDestinatarios.php', {opcion: $opcion}, 
 function (responseText){

    }).success(function(responseText) {
     $("#cargar").html(""); 
     var aux = responseText.split('|');
     for (i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) { 
        (function(i){
          setTimeout(function(){
          $("#cargar").append(aux[i]) 
          }, 500);
        }(i));
      }

  });
 }
```

No tuve tiempo de probarlo pero es una idea viable. Quizá tengas que depurarlo un poco